# Cassndra in Production

Tags: cassandra

Anybody supporting a Cassandra application in production? Curious to know about, how you handle cassandra.yaml file. Also, do you think "seed node" get's a status of master node (partially).

Comment: what do you mean by handling? just use whatever automation that you prefer - Ansible, etc. Regarding the seed node - it's not a master - it's just a node or nodes where other nodes are receiving initial information about cluster when they start - after node is started, it doesn't rely much on the seed node

Comment: 1) I thought of having cassandra.yaml in git repository and track the configuration, early stages of my experimentation. So wanted to know anybody trying the same in production?  2) Going through the documentation, seed in necessary for other new nodes to join. In case I have three nodes (all made seed nodes) created in three AZ's in AWS region, with option to add on with scaling up nodes in corresponding AZ's. Same time the seed node went down and other nodes came up might not be able to add to the ring.

Answer (score 1):

> Anybody supporting a Cassandra application in production?

Yes, my team supports several applications which use Cassandra in production.

> Curious to know about, how you handle cassandra.yaml file.

By "handle" the `cassandra.yaml` file, I assume you mean deploy with different values with automation at large scale.  We use an open source tool called [Rundeck](https://www.rundeck.com/open-source) for that.

Rundeck allows you to build options into your jobs, which is useful for properties like `cluster_name`, `seeds`, etc.  Then, you inject those options into your deploy scripts, using a regex replace (`sed`) to get them into specific properties in the yaml.  Ex:

```
sed -i "s/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'/cluster_name: '@cluster_name@'/" cassandra.yaml
```

> Also, do you think "seed node" get's a status of master node (partially).

No, a seed node is not any kind of "master" node.

**A seed node is no different from any other node.**

In theory, every node in your cluster could be a seed node for another node.  All it is, is a way for a new node to discover the network topology of the cluster.  Think of it as an entry point to the cluster.

Comment: Going through the documentation, seed in necessary for other new nodes to join. In case I have three nodes (all made seed nodes) created in three AZ's in AWS region, with option to add on with scaling up nodes in corresponding AZ's. Same time the seed node went down and other nodes came up might not be able to add to the ring.

Comment: @ManojChandran that's going to happen regardless.  You can't add a new node when any node is down.  But you are right that you may need to change a seed list to make sure that a restarted node can come back.  We actually have a Rundeck job that takes care of this.

Comment: I checked Rundeck, need to check on more. Let ask you this 
1) do you update canssandra.yaml for every node or have one file edited and copied to different nodes?
2) If you are copying cassandra.yaml file, do you rely upon environment variable or you have any other Technique?

Comment: You can bootstrap new nodes when other nodes are down.  Just give the new node a seed node that is not down at the time.  Seed node isn't a permanent designation; it just tells the new node which node to contact on first startup to get the cluster information. After this initial startup, the node caches the info about the cluster and doesn't need the seed node anymore. The one distinction about seed nodes after bootstrapping is that nodes will gossip with seed nodes more frequently than other nodes, assuming the seed node is still up, but the node will still function if its seeds are down.

Comment: @J.B.Langston you could try it, but you'll likely see this: `RuntimeException: A node required to move the data consistently is down`.

Comment: True, with vnodes, it's hard to predict which token ranges the new node will acquire and you may get that error if the new node attempts to take part of the token range owned by the dead node.  Without vnodes you have control over which nodes share replicas so you could bootstrap nodes that don't share token ranges with the dead node.  It's also possible to override this error using `-Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false`, but doing this risks data inconsistency if the other replicas aren't up to date.  But this is an orthogonal issue to seed nodes, which aren't special or permanent.